# In UWP saving HTML5 Audio stream to mp3 file

Tags: c#, uwp, media-player, html5-audio

I currently have a radio streaming App in the Windows 10 Store. Now I want to give my users the possibility to record the current stream to a mp3 File.

Does anyone of you have a suggestion on how to save the Audio Stream? I can't find the property or event that gives me the bytes to save them.

I'm using the Windows.Media.Playback.Mediaplayer class.

Thanks in advance

Christian

Comment: Can you show more about HTML5 audio?

Comment: F.e. this Stream: http://stream.sunshine-live.de/live/mp3-192/stream.sunshine-live.de/

Answer (score 2):

In general you could not get Audio Stream from `Mediaplayer` directly. However, you could monitor the audio via `Stereo Mix` device.

[image]

Set Stereo Mix as default record device. And make a audio capture via `MediaCapture` class.

```
private async Task<bool> RecordProcess()
{
    if (buffer != null)
    {
        buffer.Dispose();
    }
    buffer = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    if (capture != null)
    {
        capture.Dispose();
    }
    try
    {
        MediaCaptureInitializationSettings settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
        {
            StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Audio
        };
        capture = new MediaCapture();
        await capture.InitializeAsync(settings);
        capture.RecordLimitationExceeded += (MediaCapture sender) =>
        {
            //Stop
            //   await capture.StopRecordAsync();
            record = false;
            throw new Exception("Record Limitation Exceeded ");
        };
        capture.Failed += (MediaCapture sender, MediaCaptureFailedEventArgs errorEventArgs) =>
        {
            record = false;
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Code: {0}. {1}", errorEventArgs.Code, errorEventArgs.Message));
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.InnerException != null && ex.InnerException.GetType() == typeof(UnauthorizedAccessException))
        {
            throw ex.InnerException;
        }
        throw;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note that `Stereo` could only monitor audio that output from the same hardware device. So you need to set available playback device. For code sample you could refer [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Audio-Recorder-In-Windows-2d80c2fd).

Comment: Thank you for your advice, do you know how to decouple the volume from the system volume? Currently I have to listen at full volume, so that the recorded file is also loud.

Comment: This solution has some limitations that can not decouple the volume from the system.