# Recording screen audio in UWP

Tags: windows, audio, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I want to record game playing screen audio using UWP in windows 10, not record audio from web camera.

I tried NAudio, But it doesn’t work in UWP.
I have checked MediaCapture, I assume it can record audio or video from something like camera, not screen audio.
Although I found ScreenCapture.AudioSource property in official document, On windows 10 , This api is not supported.

Is there any way to record screen audio in UWP?

Comment: Please check this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50111816/7254781).

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT when I try to record from Stereo Mix device after enabling it, the sound is simply absent (e.g. silence). GameBar clearly does it in a different way, because it records audio from my games without any issues.